# Need to Copy data if header of table have Specific word

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with multiple sheet where sheet contain multiple data table of three column and wanted to copy Name from each sheet.

[image: Check Image Attached]

The Data is not constant in each sheet as "name" will be in Cell (B6), (F6), (B15) or (F17)

Data is in different range in each sheet for eg.in Sheet 2

> B6:D11
>     F7:H12
>     B15:D25
>     F18:H24

On Sheet 3 it will be in different range.

Need to copy Name from each table and paste it into sheet1

```
Private Sub Search_n_Copy()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rngCopy As Range, aCell As Range, bcell As Range
Dim strSearch As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

strSearch = "Name"

For Each ws In Worksheets
With ws
Set rngCopy = Nothing
    Set aCell = .Columns(2).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bcell = aCell

        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
            Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row))
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row)))
        End If

        Do
            Set aCell = .Columns(2).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bcell.Address Then Exit Do

                If rngCopy Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngCopy = .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row))
                Else
                    Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, .Rows((aCell.Row + 1) & ":" & (aCell.End(xlDown).Row)))
                End If
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

    End If

    '~~> I am pasting to sheet1. Change as applicable
If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
Range("B2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "x"
Range("A1").Select

End With
```

What I want to do is need to copy data which has Data header as "Name" and past it into Sheet 1 for all the table available in sheet and want to repeat it for all the sheet and paste it in Sheet 1 "A1"

Answer (score 0):

If they are truly tables as in a `ListObject`, then you don't need to search for words.  You can loop through the object and select the first column header by doing this...

```
x=1
For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For each tbl In ws.ListObjects
         Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x,1)=tbl.HeaderRowRange(1)
         x=x + 1
    Next tbl
Next ws
```

You can modify for specific locations to fit your code, but this is much more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, my bad it's not Table format it's normal range where range can be anywhere in the sheet and multiple time. I want name list from all table.

Comment: You may consider formatting as tables, they are easier to manage and reference.  You can find the first column header without error quickly.

Comment: I agree but not all data in sheet has name as header.

Comment: This doesn't depend on the name, only the top left header will get pulled, regardless of name.  You can access any portion of the table by using references that aren't based on content.  Here is a reference for using tables if you are interested in learning more https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables

Comment: Yes, but I have around 200 sheets in my workbook and data in all sheet is different. I need to get only list of Name from sheets. Where header is "Name"